# ExecuteSprocAccessor with Refcursor in EnterpriseLibrary 6.0 DAAB

Tags: enterprise-library

I am using VS2012, EnterpriseLibrary 6.0 [DAAB]. My connectivity to the Database [Oracle] is fine.

I have a Oracle procedure, which does not have any input parameter only the output parameter is there, which is of type RefCursor.

I am able to get the output by calling the procedure using Execute Reader and ExecuteDataset.

Now I am trying to use DatabaseExtension.ExecuteSprocAccessor. I am getting the error, which says invalid type of argument.

Can any one provide me a good example for using the ExecuteSprocAccessor.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

//GREAT NEWS //

I found the ROOT CAUSE of the issue and it is in the Enterprise Library 6.0, DataBlock source code in the class CommandAccessor.cs at Line no. 66.

Because inside the command object, the parameter collections are not there. To resolve this, we need to do the following in the SprocAccessor.cs, [The method is in Line no.97]

In the below method, the command object was inside the using statement. Due to that, the command looses it is parameter collection values when it is outside the scope of the using clause. So, I have removed the using clause and it is working fine.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Executes the stored procedure and returns an enumerable of <typeparamref name="TResult"/>.
    /// The enumerable returned by this method uses deferred loading to return the results.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameterValues">Values that will be interpret by an <see cref="IParameterMapper"/> and function as parameters to the stored procedure.</param>
    /// <returns>An enumerable of <typeparamref name="TResult"/>.</returns>
    public override IEnumerable<TResult> Execute(params object[] parameterValues)
    {
        /*
        using (DbCommand command = Database.GetStoredProcCommand(procedureName))
        {
            parameterMapper.AssignParameters(command, parameterValues);
            return base.Execute(command);
        }
        */
        DbCommand command = Database.GetStoredProcCommand(procedureName);
        parameterMapper.AssignParameters(command, parameterValues);
        return base.Execute(command);
    }
```

I am now very happy, to find the root cause. It is now working fine. Output is coming like a bullet.

Thanks

Comment: Don't you have a memory leak now? Well, non-disposed objects that will stick around until GC happens, anyway?